Fixing DNS errors on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I'm finding many problems using sites on the - some slow or lack certain details and others just won't load at all with DNS errors. More recently I just can't connect to anything. I've followed the steps on this website : https://smallbusiness.chron.com/troubleshoot-dns-linux-28781.html

Launch your Linux terminal and type "ip addr show." This will display
the current network interfaces enabled on the system. If you do not
see "eth0" or "wlan0," the issue may not be a DNS error. If there are
no network devices enabled, add one before proceeding to other
troubleshooting methods.
Type "less /etc/resolv.conf" into the terminal. This will display the
configuration for the DNS servers on your system. Write down the IP
addresses listed after "Nameserver." Type "Ping" followed by one of
the IP addresses you wrote down. If it responds "64 bytes from
128.200.1.4," then the DNS is available but not resolving names correctly. If no message was returned, then the DNS server may not be
available. Repeat this step with all the IP addresses you wrote down.

(My ip address comes up as 127.0.0.53. This site "Why does /etc/resolv.conf point at 127.0.0.53?"  has a detailed answer about this, but to be honest its too difficult for me to understand. as far as I can tell though, this isnt really my IP address, and there might be something amiss here.)

Type "Host" followed by a popular website such as www.apple.com. It
should display a statement such as "www.apple.com has address 71.16.
304.157." This indicates that the DNS server was able to contact apple.com. If it returns no data, then the DNS server needs to be
reconfigured.

The command host just returns communications error. Hence I need to reconfigure my DNS - how do I do this?

Test: Open a terminal, run sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf -- In the file that opens, change the nameserver to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, save the file and reboot the system.
